# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided installer data is not valid error

Tags: android, android-studio

I've got error INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT and there are many causes of it. That is why I checked the LogCat (Warn mode) and found this error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided installer data is not valid (uid: -1, package name: null). Data could be missing, invalid, or just not match each other. PSIC will not run.`

Any advice to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: hey, were you able to fix this?

Comment: hey, still not :/ it seems like I'm getting this error only on my old phone